# Extending the user profile in Django. Admin creation of users

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Good evening,

I am presently creating a site with Django and I extended the user with a user profile. I have a small problem though. Here is my situation:

1. I extended the user profile in order to add custom fields.
2. I added the model to the User Admin Model, so when I am adding a user, I can fill in directly the fields to create the profile.
3. Now, if I don't add ANYTHING in these new custom user fields, in the user add page, Django Admin won't throw me an error saying these fields are null (and they aren't suppose to be)
4. I want it to throw me an error in this User Add Admin page, so that the admins will HAVE to fill in a profile when adding a new user.
5. ALL the users will be added in the Admin Panel.

Is this possible? Thanks a lot!

**in admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as DjangoUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from accounts.models import UserProfile


class UserProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = UserProfile


class UserAdmin(DjangoUserAdmin):
    inlines = [ UserProfileInline,]


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

**In model.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    employee_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Number'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, empty inline is permitted and thus no further check would be taken for an empty form. You need to override it manually:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk is None:
            self.empty_permitted = False # Here

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile


class UserProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):         
    model = UserProfile                               
    form = UserProfileForm
```

Comment: Nice it worked! Do you mind explaining a bit more what the code does? Especially the Class Meta: part! Thanks mate

Comment: Also, what would be the syntax if I wanted to have only one of my fields to be empty_permitted = false? and the rest to be true?

Comment: @abisson `empty_permitted` is an undocumented parameter that `BaseForm` accepts: when a submitted form has not been changed from it initial data, and it's `empty_permitted` is `True`, `full_clean()` of the form will not perform any further validation. You could check `empty_permitted` in `django/forms/forms.py` and `django/forms/formsets.py`. If you want to have one of fields to be not empty, you could try to set `empty_permitted=True` for the form and `blank=True` for other fields.

Comment: I see. Makes sense. I thought the empty_permitted would have applied to all the fields, even the ones that have blank=true, but no, according to your sayings.

What about Class Meta: What is that?

Comment: @abisson `Meta` is inner class used by `ModelForm`, just like those in `Model`. You could ref [the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: @abisson You might want to check this same answer plus another way of doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10226924/force-the-user-to-add-an-instance-of-some-inlinemodeladmin-when-adding-a-model/10228232#10228232 It is nice. We both had the same problem yesterday ;)