# Issues with auth_user table

Tags: django, django-views

I wanted to insert the user details in auth_user table, but it gives the error of **create_user() got an unexpected keyword argument 'first_name'**

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from customer_reg.models import Customer

class Registration_Form(ModelForm):
       first_name  = forms.CharField(label=(u'First Name'))
       last_name   = forms.CharField(label=(u'Last Name'))      
       username   = forms.CharField(label=(u'User Name'))
       email      = forms.EmailField(label=(u'Email Address'))
       password   = forms.CharField(label=(u'Password'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(render_value=False))

       class Meta:
              model=Customer
              exclude=('user',)

       def clean_username(self):
                username=self.cleaned_data['username']
                try:
                      User.objects.get(username=username)
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                      return username
                raise forms.ValidationError("The Username is already taken, please try another.")
       def clean_password(self):
                password=self.cleaned_data['password']
                return password
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from customer_reg.models import Customer
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from customer_reg.forms import Registration_Form


def CustomerRegistration(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/customer_profile/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Registration_Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user=User.objects.create_user(first_name=form.cleaned_data['first_name'], last_name=form.cleaned_data['last_name'], username=form.cleaned_data['username'], email=form.cleaned_data['email'], password = form.cleaned_data['password'])

            user.save()

            customer=user.get_profile()
            customer.birthday=form.cleaned_data['birthday']
            customer.website=form.cleaned_data['website']
            customer.store=form.cleaned_data['store']
            customer.welcomemail=form.cleaned_data['welcomemail']
            customer.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/customer_profile/')
        else:
                return render_to_response('customer_register.html',{'form':form} , context_instance=RequestContext(request)) 
    else:
        ''' user is not submitting the form, show them a blank registration form '''

            form = Registration_Form()
            context={'form':form}
            return render_to_response('customer_register.html',context , context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

If I edit the views.py as

```
user=User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], email=form.cleaned_data['email'], password = form.cleaned_data['password'])
```

then it works successfully

I have already tried **firstname** as well as **first_name**

any idea where I have done the mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`create_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) manager method only accepts three arguments, `username`, `email` (optional), and `password` (optional).

Once you have created a user, you can modify the [other fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#fields), then save again.

```
user=User.objects.create_user(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], email=form.cleaned_data['email'], password = form.cleaned_data['password'])
user.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
user.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
user.save()
```

Comment: **Customer matching query does not exist.** and what about this error

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to register using admin interface you gonna have to change the admin.py inside your app

Comment: can I add my own template to admin panel which fetch the data from database and show it  to the admin...If yes then please give an example and how can i see that in my admin panel

Comment: I think you can find your answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213020/extending-the-user-profile-in-django-admin-creation-of-users